Unzipping a folder in DBFS in Databricks
I needed to upload a folder in Databricks DBFS containing a bunch of csv files. I couldn't find a way to directly upload a whole folder, so I zipped it and uploaded as a file (councils.zip). Now I'm having trouble unzipping it as it for some reason couldn't find the file.
dbutils.fs.ls('dbfs:/FileStore/')
[FileInfo(path='dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip', name='councils.zip', size=13933, modificationTime=1730297073000), FileInfo(path='dbfs:/FileStore/tables/', name='tables/', size=0, modificationTime=0)]
%sh unzip dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip
unzip:  cannot find or open dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip, dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip.zip or dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip.ZIP.
Am I missing something? I'm new to databricks. TIA

In Databricks, depending on the method you are using, you access the dbfs in a different way. Have a look at this link.
You need to run the following.
%sh 
unzip /dbfs/FileStore/councils.zip


This doesn't work. Tried it already.
unzip:  cannot find or open /dbfs/FileStore/councils.zip, /dbfs/FileStore/councils.zip.zip or /dbfs/FileStore/councils.zip.ZIP.

Interesting, such a command works for me. A direction for a solution I can think of is to browse your dbfs (you may need to put the dbfs browser onin settings) and see whether everything is as expected in the dbfs. This post suggests you may need to copy it to a subfolder first to access.

This is the way. Tested in a notebook as well. Correct source: https://docs.databricks.com/en/files/index.html#work-with-files-in-dbfs-mounts-and-dbfs-root

Ok so this is what I did to resolve the issue:
dbutils.fs.cp('dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip', 'file:/tmp/')
%sh
mkdir /tmp/extracted_council

unzip /tmp/councils.zip -d /tmp/extracted_council

dbutils.fs.cp('file:/tmp/extracted_council','dbfs:/FileStore/', recurse=True)
clean-up:
%sh
rm -rvf /tmp/councils.zip
rm -rvf /tmp/extracted_council

dbutils.fs.rm('dbfs:/FileStore/councils.zip')
